# File upload in TestCafé

Tags: javascript, testing, file-upload, automated-tests, testcafe

I'm trying to figure out how to get a file to upload in my test. My app doesn't quite match the workflow described in the app for `setFilesToUpload` so I'm having trouble.

To upload a file in my app, you click an "Upload" button which opens a native dialog. Clicking okay on the dialog brings you to a refreshed version of the index page where you can see the title of the file you have uploaded.

I have found that there is a hidden `input` element in the DOM that is used for upload. I thought I had the test working, until I tried to add an `expect` for the last part of the workflow, to ensure the upload actually worked, and that is where the test fails.

Here is the test content:

```
await t
  // other stuff to get to page with the upload button
  .click(Selector('a').withAttribute('title','Project One'))
  .setNativeDialogHandler(() => true)
  .click(Selector('.upload_one'))
  .setFilesToUpload(Selector('input').withAttribute('type','file'),
   '/path/to/movie.MOV')
  .expect(Selector('.media_name').withText('movie').exists).ok()
```

The test "passes" without the final line, but no upload is actually occurring. With the final line included, I do not ever see the native dialog in the test. It does `Waiting for an Assertion Execution` and then just fails, so I can't really tell what's going wrong. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The `t.setFilesToUpload` method only sets the value of the file input, but doesn't submit the form that contains the input. If you page has a button to force the file uploading, you should add a step that clicks this button after the .setFilesToUpload` step, or try to submit the form using a `ClientFunction`. It's hard to get a solution without looking at the code of your page.

Comment: You can see a detailed [description](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/basics/test-file-upload.html) of how to test file upload in TestCafe and inspect a runnable example [here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples/tree/master/examples/upload-files).